# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 3

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science-model

I get this error
`ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 3 for '{{node conv2d_77/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv2d_76/Relu, conv2d_77/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,32,8,3], [5,5,32,32].`

when I don't have `padding = 'same'` in my second layer in my model, and I get this error
`TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'padding'` when I have it.

**Model:**

````
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (SIZE, SIZE, 3), padding = 'same'))
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu'), padding = 'same')
model_cnn.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(rate = 0.3))

model_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model_cnn.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(rate = 0.3))

model_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_cnn.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
model_cnn.add(Dropout(rate = 0.3))
model_cnn.add(Dense(43, activation = 'softmax'))

model_cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error you're getting is likely because the input becomes too small for the network to perform a 5 by 5 convolution on. The second error is caused by the fact that you are placing the `padding` argument in the wrong place. You are currently using it for the `model.add` call, whereas you should use it with the `Conv2D` classs:

```
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'))
```